# Extend link_to function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wish to add a helper that works exactly like link_to but adds an url-parameter to the link. I tried this:

```
  def tracked_link_to(url, id, options)
    link_to('url?utm_link=#{id}', options)
  end
```

And the I tried calling it like this:

```
  <% tracked_link_to '/', 'logo' , alt: 'Zenconomy', class: 'logotype', itemprop: 'url' do %>
    <%= svg 'logotype-icon', 'icon-logo' %>
  <% end %>
```

but for some reason it doesn't output anything.

Comment: `tracked_link_to` not taking blocks... how are you supplying the block yet.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You missed equal sign. Should be:

```
<%= tracked_link_to '/', 'logo' , alt: 'Zenconomy', class: 'logotype', itemprop: 'url' do %>
```

Apart of that your implementation of `tracked_link_to` will very likely yield a different result than you are expecting. And i got to worry you, it will not be that easy to implement. Firstly, `link_to` works with strings, hashes or objects:

```
link_to('object/1')
link_to(object)
link_to(action: :show)
```

Secondly, string can already include query params:

```
tracked_linked_to('object/1?preview=true')
```

in which case you need to use `&` instead of `?`. Also, what would you do in case if string url already include `utm_param`?

Comment: I get /Users/kristoffer/web/zenconomy/source/layouts/layout.erb:20: syntax error, unexpected ')' ...logotype', itemprop: 'url' do ).to_s; @_out_buf << ' ... ^ /Users/kristoffer/web/zenconomy/source/layouts/layout.erb:36: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' /Users/kristoffer/web/zenconomy/source/layouts/layout.erb:38: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'

Comment: This is because your method doesn't expect block, as mentioned by Arup. Anyway, extending link_to doesn't seem to be a correct way, it would be much easier to extend `url_for`.